# viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener not working

Tags: android, android-studio, android-viewpager

I am using Android Studio to develop an app targeting API level 22 and using compileSdkVersion level is 23.
When I am trying to implement `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener()` in below code, it gives

> setOnPageChangeListener is deprecated.

```
 viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {}
```

What I want to do with `viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener()` is this:

```
viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            txtPropertyOverviewImageCount.setText(position + "/" + GalleryImages.length);
            //GalleryImage have no of item is same size of viewpager
            //i want O/P like this 
            // 1/8
            // 2/8
            // 3/8
            LogUtils.Log_e("CurrentPage", position + "");
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

yes `setOnPageChangeListener` is deprecated in favour of `addOnPageChangeListener` which allows you to register more than one listener, in case you need it. You can find the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#addOnPageChangeListener(android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener))

Answer (score 8):

Hi the onPageChangeListener is deprecated..Use this..

---

```
ViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```

Then it should work